# How to make a large mesh smaller and workable?

Tags: rendering, mesh

I created a piece of wire in Cycles which uses an array modifier and curve modifier.
(the piece is e.g. 5cm and is used in my scene at several locations (e.g. a wire of 25meter distance, etc...).
I need the detail from the wire because I want to zoom in with the camera and fly over the scene.

When I work in Blender, the editing is slow but ok. Rendering however is very very slow It takes more than 10minutes to build BVH (or something like that..).
The modifiers to my model are already applied, so I can't undo this.

At the top of the Blender dialog I see:

```
v2.72 | Verts: 13.926.207 | Faces: 13.960.114 | Tris: 27.912.399 | Objects: 1/29
```

As a blender beginner, how can I make this blender file more 'workable' (lighter/faster/...)? 
Now I need to wait 20 or 25 minutes to render 1 frame, which I think is not thàt complex.

Comment: Please include a screen image and your system specs if that suits you.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger img: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=CB15F1A932B364BE&id=CB15F1A932B364BE%2120042&v=3
quick specs: win8.1, 8GB ram, core i7, ssd drive, nvidia geforce gtx 660

Comment: Change of request. Can you show your Closest Close up of fence in some render (low quality is fine).  Close up of fence links in wireframe mode.  Is the mesh density minimal there?

Comment: At one point. I had a 4GB average laptop. Now I have a more powerful 12GB laptop.  Blender behaves much better. (Non Scientific).  I never encourage people to spend.  Ummmmm ..... If I had a desktop like I think you do, I would be tempted to double your memory.

Comment: I've just doubled my memory 8GB to 16GB and now I see that blender takes up 14GB and it works rather smooth. Wow, what a difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways to reduce interaction time. Consider Please

- Work in wireframe mode when that is possible.  You need not work in render mode all the time.
- Change maximum draw type for some objects to wireframe
- Turn off Eye display of less important items for preview in outliner.  Camera Render Stays On.  Sometimes Groups can help this.
- Bill board texture technique game style. A complex fence might be rendered once and then the texture put on blender planes. Crude and quick display substitute. Eye Display Only. Camera Render off.  Same location as the complex fence.
- Working in local mode sometimes to isolate editing ... key / to enter and the same key to exit

Once a array modifier with repeat N on a meshA is applied and become meshFinal ...

- the number of vertices of MeshFinal = N * (number of vertices of MeshA)

Once can reduce such vertices sometimes by using a Particle System with can produces meshes with a shared vertex datablock.   Configuration Settings .. Editing ... Duplicate Data ... Mesh may affect this.  The object size overhead is present in this case.

Comment: is it a good thing to apply modifiers directly?

Comment: thanks, some good tips here. the Eye display is very useful.

Comment: If a person have very specific (more work) artistic/visual needs then the modifier must be applied.  I tend to leave modifiers on until I determine that need. Modifier composition can sometimes keep me from applying.